# Processing order of messages in Kafka stream having topology with more than one source

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

```java
Topology streamTopology = new Topology();

streamTopology.addSource("Source1", "Topic1").addSource("Source2", "Topic2")
              .addProcessor("Processor1", () -> new TestStreamProcessor1(), "Source1")
              .addProcessor("Processor2", () -> new TestStreamProcessor2(), "Source2")
              .addStateStore(Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore("TestStatestore"),
                        Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()), "Processor1", "Processor2");
KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(streamTopology, props);
streams.start();
```

If messages are coming on both topics, in what order the messages are processed and passed to the statestore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no ordering guarantee for this case. Kafka only guarantees in-order delivery per partition, but not across partitions (or across topics---data in different topics is in different partitions obviously).

Note though, that using the Processor API, adding a store is not sufficient by itself to put data into the store. Your need to write code in `Processor#process()` to put data into the store.