# kafka streams multi-topic sub-topology message processing order flow

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I've read the documentation from here:

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/architecture.html#flow-control-with-timestamps

> Kafka Streams regulates the progress of streams by the timestamps of data records by attempting to synchronize all source streams in terms of time. By default, Kafka Streams will provide your application with event-time processing semantics. This is important especially when an application is processing multiple streams (i.e., Kafka topics) with a large amount of historical data. For example, a user may want to re-process past data in case the business logic of an application was changed significantly, e.g. to fix a bug in an analytics algorithm. Now it is easy to retrieve a large amount of past data from Kafka; however, without proper flow control, the processing of the data across topic partitions may become out-of-sync and produce incorrect results.

> As mentioned in the Concepts section, each data record in Kafka Streams is associated with a timestamp. Based on the timestamps of the records in its stream record buffer, stream tasks determine the next assigned partition to process among all its input streams.

That last part is what my question is about.

Example: I have a sub-topology which has two topics within it, connected only via a shared state store. (For simplicity sake) Both topics only have one partition. Topic A has messages with a ts of 1, 3, 6 and topic B has messages with a ts 2, 4, 5

When I start the app, will the task processing order be a depth first process guaranteed to be ordered by timestamp between partitions, like so; a1, b2, a3, b4, b5, a6?

If not, how can I achieve this guarantee?

This answer is what caused me to be hesitant about processing order. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50279474/4354090